# Aptana Studio 3's error log location?

Tags: logging, aptana

When formatting a file, Aptana reports:

> Unable to format. See error log for details.

I haven't been able to find the error log.

Answer (score 32):

You could access it via Help > Aptana > View Log File.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is no View Log File under Help on the Mac. I finally did some more digging, and found it under "about Aptana" under the Apple hidden beneath a button labelled "Installation Details".

Comment: Are you in Web perspective?  The menu only appears when you are in the specific perspective.

Comment: In any case, the best way to have this issue solved, you should submit an issue with a code segment that trigger it.
http://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa

Comment: @Cliff The instructions on Michael's response are correct for Mac OS as of the current version of Aptana Studio (3.1.3). No more need to dig inside the "About Aptana" window.

Answer (score 10):

According to the docs it should be in the current workspace /.metadata/.log

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Accessing+the+Log+File

Answer (score 0):

```
!ENTRY com.aptana.formatter.epl 4 0 2012-12-07 09:47:47.868
!MESSAGE (Build 3.2.2.201208201020) [ERROR] com.aptana.formatter.epl/debug Error while formatting the code in your editor.

Please submit a bug report through Studio's support and include the relevant code which triggered this error.

You may also turn on the com.aptana.formatter.epl/debug at the Studio's Troubleshooting preference page to log more details about this error.
```

Comment: Put your codes in code block. It improves your answer readability.

Answer (score 0):

use the installation to repair it.

> Run installation  > Chose Repair > Done