# Aptana freezing regularly in Windows 7

Tags: aptana, aptana3

Seems to be since updating Aptana 3.4 (3.4.0.201304151603 to be precise) that it regularly freezes up - greys out and displays "Not responding".

It doesn't freeze up straight away, usually after editing and saving for a few minutes. Generally seems to freeze while editing code, usually PHP.

My log file did report issues with the Subversion plugin, but I've since removed this entirely and still face the same issues.

My OS is Windows 7 32-bit.

Any suggestions on how to remedy such problems in Aptana would be greatly appreciated as this renders it pretty useless :(.

Comment: How long do you wait when it says it isn't responding? When it is doing something, Aptana won't necessarily be good about informing Windows it is busy. Sometimes mine will come back with a not responding and 10 seconds later it is fine if I just leave it alone. Granted, different versions (mine is a little older).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @SarahKemp - just left it for 30+ mins and it hasn't come back yet! Keep having to force close it and restart. Also noticed it only seems to be doing this while editing using the PHP editor.

Comment: Interesting. Are you working on a very large project? Does Aptana show what operation it is attempting to complete when it freezes? Indexing maybe? Rebuilding Workspace? You could try turning off the "Build Automatically" setting under Project. What is the Project Nature? Do you reference other projects? Are you working from files on a network drive or local files? Is there anything useful in the log file? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923741/where-does-aptana-studio-3-store-it-error-log-file

Comment: Not particularly large, 100+ files. I do have a 20,000+ file project in Aptana but issue occurs when this is closed. No indication of what it's doing when the issue occurs - the Progress View is usually empty when it occurs. Will try turning off build automatically just to see! Project nature is "Web - Primary" and "PHP". No other projects referenced. Files are on the local drive, and the .log file doesn't show any obvious errors - just exits. Thanks again for your input @SarahKemp - greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you. I have seen several bug reports come up since Aptana released 3.4 - perhaps you could hunt down a 3.3 version and see if that works for you. I'm on 3.3.2 (I believe this is the last release before 3.4) and it is stable for me.

Answer (score 4):

Deleting the log file seems to work for me.
Its full of pretty useless stuff for a regular user anyway and when it gets too big - boom: not responding.

Try deleting the log file ( /[yourworkspace]/.metadata/.log ),
emptying your windows temp folder (C:\Users[your user name]\AppData\Local\Temp) and run aptana as an administrator (you can make this default behaviour by editing the properties of the task bar / start menu icon for Aptana)

Maybe a new version will come out with a fix for this OR the option to turn off logging completely. Its the log file causing this issue for sure.

Comment: where does the aptana log file live? what is it called?

Answer (score 2):

Do you use a git repository? Mine is freezing, too, but when I rename the .git directory to something else, the freezing stops. I'm on Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.0.201304151603. It's very annoying because I do use git. I haven't been able to track down exactly what about the git integration is causing this.

Comment: No, I've not been using git. Afraid I couldn't find a solution for this issue other than completely reinstalling Windows - greater problems may have been at play!

Comment: +1 im also using git and it freezes sometimes, tried Innate's suggestions but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

So I have been having the same problem with Aptana Studio 3. I have followed this set of instructions found here: 
http://youtu.be/RYobTLq_hms?list=UUtL_0WLPWmHZE_HcX48F96w

Or here are the instructions if you do not want a video to watch...

1. Goto www.JAVA.com/en/download/ and download the newest Java Runtime Environment
2. Open up C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Aptana Studio 3\AptanaStudio3.ini with anything but notepad (Open with WordPad or Notepad++)
3. BEFORE the -vmargs line add:

   -vm
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe

... then SAVE and CLOSE

4 . Finally open Aptana Studio 3. Now your problem should be solved and Aptana should be pointing to the newest version of JAVA.

I hope that this fix helps you as much as it has helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the log file didn't work for me, but when viewing the log file, it talked about

> The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

So I deleted the workspace file (/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workbench.xml) which just stores what files you had open when you closed the application and the problem was installed solved (with seeminly no unexpected side-effects)

Answer (score 0):

I still have this problem.  It seems more often than not it hangs on startup.  Win 7 64bit. One time I deleted the .metadata folder, then recreated a blank one it it worked.  but it no longer works.  One time I rebooted the system and it worked.  The fix that works 1 time doesn't the next.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the lines:

```
-vm

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\*javaversion*\bin\
```

to the `.ini` file:

```
C:\Users\*youruser*\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio\AptanaStudio3.ini
```

solved the freezing issue for me.