# Aptana Studio 3 hangs on project open w/ Mac OSX 10.7

Tags: macos, aptana, osx-mountain-lion

So, this is the 3rd time I've reinstalled Aptana Studio 3 (3.4.2 this time). I am working on a web project with .php, .js, .css, .html and a few other file types.  After several weeks of successful work, Aptana will hang on startup.  It will load my project and files, but then all I get is a beach ball and aside from moving the main window, I can't do anything (menu clicks, file close, nada). This state will then persist no matter how many restarts I do.  The only solution is to send Applications/AptanaStudio to the trash and download a fresh copy. Then, it doesn't remember my old project and starts ok.  Could be just a coincidence but twice now when this happened I was editing .js files. Anyone else having problems with this?

Comment: I too have similar issues with Aptana, and it is seriously driving me nuts. I will set up my environment and my debugging servers for several projects only to have to tear down the plugins folder and start all over again. And it is random as to why it happens. sometimes it happens and I am sure that it is because I have too many editor tabs open, then I'll close all my editors and try to start again only to see the beach ball. Terribly frustrating

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My old answer didn't really work.. What really helped:

(on windows) in this folder:

```
[my workspace folder]\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\[my project(s)]\
```

delete the `.markers` file (I think this are breakpoints set)

Answer (score 1):

Today my installation of Aptana Studio 3 crashed on rebuilding the workspace and was not able to restart again. (splash-screen flashes and disappears within a second).
Program start with "-console"-option failed, so did deleting the ".markers"-Files.

My solution for finding out the crashing plugin:

- rename plugins-folder within Aptana-Installation: "[...]/.metadatata/.plugins", eg. to  ".plugins.bak"
- Restart Aptana -> new ".plugins"-Folder will be created automatically along with the core plugins and basic setup
- Close Aptana
- rename the new plugins folder and reset the .bak-folder to ".plugins" (In Windows use renaming by console ("ren"), it won't work in Windows-Explorer)
- Rename all plugins in the original folder by putting e.g. "old."in front of the directoryname (so they are disabled)
- copy new Plugins from new plugins-Folder in original Folder
  Program should start smoothly (without most individual settings and preferences)
- one by one enable the plugins by resetting the original name und you'll find out which one causes the crashing and leave it disabled.
- Start with restoring the core plugins.
- You can re-install the failing one later by using the marketplace.

I was lucky and sure it's rather a dirty solution that took about half an hour, but for me the problem was solved and I could avoid reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use git/svn to manage your projects?
I had a similar problem, Aptana freezed while starting up.

(Well, starting up was ok, but then it loaded open projects, what was ok as well, but to freeze when it tried to update the vcs tags in the project explorer; on Win7 64)

I could resolve this by manually committing all uncommitted changes in all open projects.
In a console type for all open projects:

```
cd D:\path\to\project
cd /path/to/project
git commit -am "Some commit message"
```

(edit: Looks like it was a problem with files that got moved / deleted / renamed and some mismatch of the working directory, the git repro and open files / tabs in aptana. I didn't care to track it down exactly, because git commit fixed it and I needed to work on..)

Comment: by the way, I got the idea from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166386/aptana-freezing-regularly-in-windows-7

Comment: Thanks RafiK -- I am using it on a Mac under OS 10.7 -- I'll see if I can locate your .markers file and try deleting it before launching Aptana Studio.  If so I'll come back and mark your suggestion as the answer.  I don't think I'm using git (though I have it installed) because I'm just messing around in my local dev directory.

Answer (score 0):

Rafik's solution worked for me.

Aptana was hung on startup trying to rebuild workspace.

I deleted `/Documents/Aptana Studio 3` `Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/<name of project>.markers` on the one open project, reopened Aptana, and it's no longer hung!

This is on `Mac OS X 10.7.5`